# How can we show only specific no. of view in iCarousel, if we have 'n' no. of views?

Tags: icarousel

Actually, I have 5 views in iCarousel, it displaying all the five views, but I need to show only 3 views instead of 5 views how can i achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Override this function in your ViewController to specify the number of items

```
// ViewController.m
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    return 3;
}
```

Make sure the ViewController is set as the delegate and datasource

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>
```